# Inverted function keys (F1-F12) on HP Pavilion dv4t

Tags: hp-pavilion, function-keys, fn-key

(I know there have already been a lot of questions about this, but none of them mentioned the dv4t specifically.)

I'm thinking about getting an HP Pavilion dv4t-4200 or -5100, but something that's really irritating me is that by default the function keys (F1-F12) are "inverted"—without holding the Fn key, the function keys do things like change the brightness, change or mute the volume, and switch to an external display. Only if you hold Fn will they actually produce F1, F2, etc. This is not how keyboards are supposed to work. Is there any way to disable this "feature" *that has been verified to work on the **HP Pavilion dv4t-4200** or **HP Pavilion dv4t-5100***? I don't want to buy one unless this is possible.

Edit: One [proposed solution](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02035108?jumpid=reg_r1002_usen_c-001_title_r0001) works on the Pavilion dv7 ([confirmed here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Notebook-PC-Questions/HP-Pavilion-dv7-4080us-not-using-the-f-keys-by-default-how-to/m-p/321966/highlight/true#M13557)), the Pavilion dm1 ([confirmed here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware/how-to-use-function-keys-F1-to-F12-without-presseing-Fn-key/m-p/908559/highlight/true#M54255)), the Envy 17 ([confirmed here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware/how-to-use-function-keys-F1-to-F12-without-presseing-Fn-key/m-p/929035/highlight/true#M55008)), and the Pavilion G6 ([confirmed here](http://www.orbiter-forum.com/showthread.php?s=76b4a1105db9e17520a2eccb0ff71c49&p=321965&postcount=4)). ***I need to know whether this works on the HP Pavilion dv4t-4200 or -5100***.

Comment: Actually, all Apple computers do that same exact thing, and now more computer manufacturers are following suit. That model is not the first, nor will it be the last.

Comment: @R3TRI8UTI0N Well, at least in OSX you can disable that. (I think.)

Comment: I have never seen the option to be able to do this. Though it is possible I am wrong. Either way, why are you so dead-set against this "feature"?

Comment: On certain models (dv7 for sure) there's a BIOS setting to do so. (h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02035108) I'm not exactly "dead-set"; I just find it very annoying. I've been eying other brands too, and lack of a solution might tip the balance in favor of a Dell Inspiron 4z.

Comment: Ah I see. And I mean't I have never seen an option in macs. Other computers I can definitely see that being in the BIOS

Comment: (Well, Macs too. http://i.stack.imgur.com/LRny7.jpg)

Comment: I can confirm it's possible to disable in the BIOS settings of the Pavilion g6, but you already have confirmation for other models anyway...

Comment: Cool I learned something today. @Bob No crap bob... I already agreed it's possible to disable them in other BIOS's.

Answer (score -1):

Look in the BIOS settings, there's usually a toggle that sets the Fn keys to either 'music control' or 'F-keys'

Comment: Thanks, but I already mentioned that in the comments. I'm looking for *verification* that this actually is possible on the *dv4t*.